# What format is the RabbitMQ uptime?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, time-format

I have a query which I am running:

```
python rabbitmqadmin -H xxxxxxxxxx -P 443 -u xxxxxxxxxx -p xxxxxxxxxxx -s list nodes name type running uptime
```

and I am getting back:

```
+------------------+------+---------+----------+
|       name       | type | running |  uptime  |
+------------------+------+---------+----------+
| rabbit@localhost | disc | True    | 69193749 |
+------------------+------+---------+----------+
```

What format is the field uptime in? How long is 69193749? Is that in milliseconds?

Answer (score 2):

It is in **milliseconds**.

You can use one of the methods [here](https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2019/12/16/how-to-get-rabbitmq-uptime/) to get the time in seconds and then you can compare to your command, e.g.

```
sudo rabbitmqctl eval "{Total_Wallclock_Time, _} = erlang:statistics(wall_clock),Total_Wallclock_Time div 1000."
```

I also tried restarting the server and run the command a few times in succession, and that confirmed it is in milliseconds.

```
~$ sudo systemctl restart rabbitmq-server
~$ rabbitmqadmin list nodes name type running uptime
+----------------------+------+---------+--------+
|         name         | type | running | uptime |
+----------------------+------+---------+--------+
| rabbit@comp          | disc | True    | 7510   |
+----------------------+------+---------+--------+
~$ rabbitmqadmin list nodes name type running uptime
+----------------------+------+---------+--------+
|         name         | type | running | uptime |
+----------------------+------+---------+--------+
| rabbit@comp          | disc | True    | 12512  |
+----------------------+------+---------+--------+
~$ rabbitmqadmin list nodes name type running uptime
+----------------------+------+---------+--------+
|         name         | type | running | uptime |
+----------------------+------+---------+--------+
| rabbit@comp          | disc | True    | 22519  |
+----------------------+------+---------+--------+
```

Then running the previously suggested command

```
sudo rabbitmqctl eval "{Total_Wallclock_Time, _} = erlang:statistics(wall_clock),Total_Wallclock_Time div 1000."
```

now gave me

```
38
```

seconds.

It is interesting I also tried `rabbitmqadmin --help` but I could not find information about the format there, nor when I googled the problem, so a very valid question.

Answer (score 2):

The `rabbitmqadmin` utility works by making REST calls to the RabbitMQ API. This is the equivalent `curl` statement to get the uptime:

```
lbakken@shostakovich ~
$ curl -4su 'guest:guest' localhost:15672/api/nodes | jq '.[0].uptime'
998893

lbakken@shostakovich ~
$ curl -4su 'guest:guest' localhost:15672/api/nodes | jq '.[0].uptime'
1003897
```

As @matthias points out, there is no documentation of what units are used. I can add that to our docs, but I'm not exactly sure of the best place to do it.

If you run `rabbitmqctl status`, you can see the uptime in seconds:

```
$ ./sbin/rabbitmqctl status
Status of node rabbit@shostakovich ...
Runtime

OS PID: 172928
OS: Linux
Uptime (seconds): 1113
...
...
...
```

...and, as shown [in the linked blog post](https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2019/12/16/how-to-get-rabbitmq-uptime/), the following will show uptime in seconds:

```
$ curl -4su 'guest:guest' localhost:15672/api/nodes | jq '.[0].uptime / 1000 | floor'
1194
```

The value increases about every 5 seconds due to how management statistics are updated.